# The source of a Nietzsche quote

Tags: history-of-philosophy, nietzsche, quote

I remember Nietzsche wrote "it is OK to philosophize by just touching on subjects" instead of developing a systematic way. In which book was it? Or do I misremember the quote?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards.

Comment: I don't know if this is one of his quotes, but it definitely describes Nietzsche's aphoristic style

Comment: Those Greeks were superficial - from profundity ! /The Gay Sci. pref., 4/; This will to appearance, to simplification, to masks, to cloaks, in short, to  the 
surface (for  every surface is a  cloak) is countered by the sublime tendency of the man in  search of knowledge to  take and to want to  take things deeply /Beyond Good and evil, 230 (Our Virtues)/ ?

Comment: @sand1 thanks for your help. But I think this is not the quote I remember :(